# AWS, Lambda, Java, POJO, custom json property name

Tags: java, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pojo

Making first attempts with Lambda. Created code, deployed, test works, but:

```
public String handleRequest(MyType inObj, Context context) {
    // logging inObj here
}
```

POJO class

```
public class MyType {
    String prop;
    String otherProp;
}
```

when invoking, I give following payload:

```
{ "prop": "val1", "other_prop": "val2" }
```

As you can see, I want to give json in snake_case.
When lambda logs, I can see that

> inObj.prop == "val1"
>
> inObj.otherProp == "null".

When I change JSON from snake_case to camelCase, it is deserialized properly and otherProp == "val2".
I tried adding @JsonProperty("other_prop") to the field, adding getter and setter (in camelCase) and adding @JsonProperty to those (random guess), but nothing changed.

Q: how can I describe MyType class so that it is properly deserialized from snake_case to camelCase by AWS Lambda?

Answer (score 6):

See note in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-programming-model-req-resp.html

> Note
>
> You shouldn't rely on any other features of serialization
> frameworks such as annotations. If you need to customize the
> serialization behavior, you can use the raw byte stream to use your
> own serialization.

So you need to serialize the objects from the inputstream to make use of annotations.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-handler-io-type-stream.html

```
package example;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestStreamHandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context; 

public class Hello implements RequestStreamHandler {
    public static void handler(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) throws IOException {
        // TODO Serialize Object from inputStream
    }
}
```

Comment: Woot! Thats exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

This looks somewhat similar to [Capitalized fields with POJO Input Handlers for Java AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47133792/capitalized-fields-with-pojo-input-handlers-for-java-aws-lambda/53127510#53127510)

Similar to the answer there, you could try using a pojo with **public** fields that are named exactly the same as the json field